# cpan not using configured repo instead trying to connect to cpan.org when installing perl modules

Tags: perl, cpan

I have installed perl and cpan in an automated shell script.
configure only one local repo from the script itself as below:

```
echo o conf urllist https://localrepo.mylab.mycompany.com/cpan
echo o conf commit
```

and it configured and wrote to config file:

```
commit: wrote '/root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'
```

When I displayed the urllist after this, it shown properly as :

```
urllist           
[https://localrepo.mylab.mycompany.com/cpan]
Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items
```

But when I try to install a perl module, it is trying to connect to cpan.org instead of localrepo

```
cpan -f -i inc::latest
20:16:59  Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
20:16:59  
20:16:59  Trying with
20:16:59      /usr/bin/wget -O "/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp18229"
20:16:59  to get
20:16:59      https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
20:16:59  --2023-02-21 15:46:59--  https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
20:16:59  Resolving cpan.org (cpan.org)... 151.101.193.55, 151.101.129.55, 151.101.65.55, ...
20:19:21  Connecting to cpan.org (cpan.org)|151.101.193.55|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
20:21:27  Connecting to cpan.org (cpan.org)|151.101.129.55|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
```

I want to know why its connecting to cpan.org and how to make it to connect to localrepo.

Tried to delete all other repositories in the url list and added only one repo.
Still not connecting to configured repo., if urllist is displayed it shows only one configured repo. and it never shows cpan.org repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: `o conf pushy_https 0`

If the `pushy_https` setting is true (or `undef`), the CPAN client ignores the `urllist` setting and goes straight to CPAN, willy-nilly. This was added a couple years ago in response to a repository spoofing attack. The attack may not have involved Perl directly (my memory is unclear on this), but p5p decided to respond to it anyway. Making this the default means that the default behavior is safe, but it makes things a little more complex for those of us who keep their own mirrors, and the need to do this is not obvious.

Comment: Interesting. That's not how it's documented ("use https to cpan.org when possible, otherwise use http to cpan.org and issue a warning")

Comment: Agreed. All the docs seem to say is what happens if pushy_https is true. They are, or were the last time I looked, silent on what to do if you don't want to use cpan.org at all.

Comment: The documentation was included in my earlier comment, and it clearly says what it does when it's false. And it's different than what you said it actually does.

Comment: We read the documentation differently, then. I read it as saying "Use https to connect to cpan.org if the necessary SSL modules can be loaded. If they can not, connect to cpan.org using http."

Anyway, it does not matter what the documentation says, or what either of us thinks it says. What matters is what it actually does. My experience says that the CPAN client pays attention to urllist only when pushy_https is explicitly false. Do You have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: The docs says setting to zero allows `cpan` to connect to cpan.org without https, and the answers says it allows `cpan` to connect to hosts other than cpan.org. Those are very different things.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. It was working fine without setting pusshy_https to '0' in v2.27, when the script ran 'yum install perl-CPAN', cpan upgraded to v2.33 then it caused the problem.